# Call a Smart contract function using ethers.js. Trying to request the ABI of the contract with etherscan api and call its method

Tags: smartcontracts, web3js, abi, ethers.js

I'm trying to call `mint` function using ABI of my test smart contract on goerli - (https://goerli.etherscan.io/address/0x636c6090348b03a46d73ecc40f005e43662f515d#code) . I'm sending request using `axios` and etherscan api like this:

```
const url = `https://api-goerli.etherscan.io/api
?module=contract
&action=getabi
&address=${contractAddress}
&apikey=${apiKey}`;
```

Then Im getting abi:

```
async function getABI() {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get(url);
    const abi = response.data.result;
    return abi;
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

It's working, I can get the abi, checked it. But when I'm trying to call `mint` method in my fucntion:

```
async function mint() {
  try {
    const promises = privateKeys.map(async (privateKey) => {
      const abi = await getABI();
      const signer = new ethers.Wallet(privateKey, provider);
      const contract = new ethers.Contract(contractAddress, abi, signer);
      const encodeMint = contract.methods[method](
        ...Object.values(params)
      ).encodeABI();
      const gasLim = await contract.methods[method](
        ...Object.values(params)
      ).estimateGas();
      const gasPrice = gas * Math.pow(10, 9);
      const tx = {
        to: contractAddress,
        data: encodeMint,
        gasPrice: gasPrice,
        gasLimit: gasLim,
      };
      let txHash;
      while (true) {
        try {
          const signedTx = await signer.sign(tx);
          txHash = await provider.sendTransaction(signedTx);
          break;
        } catch (e) {
          console.log(`Failed to send transaction, trying again...`);
          await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
        }
      }
```

**It's giving me an error:**

Error occurred while sending transaction TypeError: no matching function (argument="key", value="methods", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=6.1.0)
at makeError (C:\Users\dmitr\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\Node-js\node_modules\ethers\lib.commonjs\utils\errors.js:114:21)
at assert (C:\Users\dmitr\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\Node-js\node_modules\ethers\lib.commonjs\utils\errors.js:138:15)
at assertArgument (C:\Users\dmitr\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\Node-js\node_modules\ethers\lib.commonjs\utils\errors.js:150:5)
at Interface.getFunctionName (C:\Users\dmitr\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\Node-js\node_modules\ethers\lib.commonjs\abi\interface.js:337:39)
at new WrappedMethod (C:\Users\dmitr\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\Node-js\node_modules\ethers\lib.commonjs\contract\contract.js:175:38)
at Contract.getFunction (C:\Users\dmitr\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\Node-js\node_modules\ethers\lib.commonjs\contract\contract.js:624:17)
at Object.get (C:\Users\dmitr\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\Node-js\node_modules\ethers\lib.commonjs\contract\contract.js:565:39)
at C:\Users\dmitr\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\Node-js\minter.js:48:35
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
at async Promise.all (index 0) {
code: 'INVALID_ARGUMENT',
argument: 'key',
value: 'methods'

That's how I'm calling method:
const method = `mint`;
const params = {};

Mint function doesn't expecting inputs:

```
  {
    "inputs": [],
    "name": "mint",
    "outputs": [],
    "stateMutability": "payable",
    "type": "function"
  },
```

so I thoung, that I don't need to use `const params` like an argument :

```
      const encodeMint = contract.methods[method](
        ...Object.values(params)
      ).encodeABI();
      const gasLim = await contract.methods[method](
        ...Object.values(params)
```

But got the same problem.

So, I need help/advice how to fix this error. And ,if I want to use this can like mint bot, Is it rational to send a request (which delays the execution time of the code) or is it better to get the abi somehow differently?